# Bash-profile error and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, bash

I tried to edit my bash_profile earlier. I think I put a space after the '=' and then I couldn't use any command line tools. I've now managed to get them back, although my terminal now says I don't have rails installed. I sudo install it, but it fails because it asks me to replace the rake gem with the rake executable. I say no to that request. I have been using rails to follow a tutorial. Unless it has been wiped, I have it. There must be something wrong with the path, but I don't know what the bash_profile should be. It is currently:

```
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH
PATH=/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
PATH=Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into $
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I don't know how to go about fixing this.Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer.

Comment: Did you try to run a [which](http://ss64.com/osx/which.html) command to locate your ruby package. That should give you the path.

Comment: Which ruby returns:/usr/bin/ruby. Are you able to recommend a resource for where I can find how to set my bash_profile? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines replace the entire PATH with a single directory:

```
PATH=/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
PATH=Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin
```

There is now absolutely nothing in your command search path except `"Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin"`, with missing / so that it only works if you're in the root directory, no less.

Then you add some stuff to the PATH without replacing what's there, which is fine, but then you do this:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Which completely undoes all of that and gives you just the above literal path.

You generally don't want to assign to `PATH` without a `$PATH` somewhere on the right hand side.

Comment: echo $PATH returns: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin. My bash_profile now has: $PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
$PATH=/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH
$PATH=/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
$PATH=/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin
$PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin